# Json.net deserialize dictionary and assign dictionary key to dictionary value's member variable

Tags: c#, json.net

Let's say I have a json like this

```json
"inventory":{
  "sh0001":{
     "price":100
  },
  "sh0002":{
     "price":50
  }
}
```

And I want to deserialize it with Json.net, into a data structure like this

```cs
class Store
{
  public Dictionary<string, Item> inventory;
}
class Item
{
  [JsonIgnore] public string id;
  public int price;
}
```

I want to use the dictionary key (e.g. "sh0001") and assign them to the value object's Id variable (item.id = "sh0001").

---

---

One obvious solution is to add a method like `Store.OnJsonDeserialized()`, and maybe call it within a factory method `Store.FromJson(string json)`, such that we won't forget to and call it after Deserialization...

```cs
  public void OnJsonDeserialized()
  {
     foreach(var kvp in inventory)
        kvp.value.id = kvp.key;
  }

  public static Store FromJson(string json)
  {
     var newObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Store>(json);
     newObj.OnJsonDeserialized();
     return newObj;
  }
```

But what if we now want to Embed the Store class into another class (e.g. Company), and deserialize that from JSON instead?

```cs
class Company
{
  public Store[] stores;
}
```

Now `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(json)` will not work as intended, and item.Id won't be assigned.

Is there any better way to do the Deserialization in this case?
Thank you.

Comment: You must use this class Public Store [] stores; When you have a list of stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after typing the question, I figure out that the Json.net supports a few [serialization callback attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) (from `System.Runtime.Serialization`), which is exactly what I need.

```
    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Member4 = "This value was set after deserialization.";
    }
```

Alternatively, instead of using a Dictionary, there's also [KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2?view=net-5.0), which reduces the need for duplicated dictionary key. The downside is that it won't deserialize and serialize to the desired json format I want by default, and require some customization.

Comment: Yes, but seems like I can't accept it until tomorrow.

Comment: I see, didn't new about such delay to accept answer. By the way, your JSON example is syntactically wrong. My personal opinion is that if you have a well defined json structure. Always have simple object that it deserializes into(In VisualStudio, you can do this simply by copying the json object, then click `Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as Classes`), and then do whatever modifications you wanna do by creating new specialized objects, etc.